# How do I fix these compiler errors in Apple Crunch?

Tags: android, open-source

I've been looking around and I finally got the full source code for a game called [*Apple-Crunch* from Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/apple-crunch/).  But when I put it into my project, the source code included so many errors in the class files such as:

- cannot be resolved into a type
- the constructor is undefined
- the method method() is undefined for the type Sprite class.java

I downloaded the source directly from the [command-line](http://code.google.com/p/apple-crunch/source/checkout) and noticed errors popping up on my project.  Since I couldn't figure out how to import the actual folder into my workspace (it wouldn't show up on existing projects) I decided to copy and overwrite the folders into the project.

The errors were still there so I looked at the class files and noticed that the classes with errors extended from `RokonActivity`.  I then proceeded to add to the libs folder the Rokon library in hopes to fix the errors.  Sadly it didn't work and now I don't what to do to fix the errors.

How do I fix the errors without having to manually change the code?  The source code should be fully functional so why are there errors?

Comment: Likely you are missing libraries [that need to be defined](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm). And you may want to slow down a bit, find something simpler first.

Comment: Do you recomend anything simpler?  Something more exciting than tetris?  Plus, isn't changing an open-source code suppose 2 be easy and for practice? It seems to me that the only hard part of an open-source code is setting it up.

Comment: Nope, it's not *supposed* to be easy, and typically it's difficult. I don't know of anything else you can switch to, it's just my recommendation.

Comment: Well I'm just trying to set it up so I can run it, then I can change it.  Like adding new features or or removing settings i wouldnt like.

Answer (score 3):

Send the developer a [few euros](http://code.google.com/p/apple-crunch/) (more than two) and an email asking for help setting up Eclipse with his project. Support open source and get the exact help you need. WIN-WIN.

Answer (score 0):

AppleCrunch is based on Rokon which I think is not maintained anymore. Rokon is based on LibGDX which is very actively maintained. My advice is stick with LibGDX. An alternative is AndEngine but I found the lack of documentation sickening when I was a beginner so I chose LibGDX, but the choice is yours.

Comment: this was an open-source project that used rokon instead of libgdx.  I'm not that experienced so I don't how to change the library without having to change the coding.  In the future I plan to use LibGDX.